# how to apply numpy flatten?

Tags: python, numpy

There is a numpy array of the form (50 100 100). Please explain how to apply the flatten function to the last two dimensions, i.e. convert it to the form (50 10000).

You can do it with a python list generator, but I would like to find a smarter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `flatten`, you can use [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html). To use it, you need to pass the shape you want the array to become. You know you want the first dimension to be 50 and you can pass -1 as the second dimension, which tells numpy to figure out what that value should be.

```py
arr.reshape(50,-1)
```